# Positive definiteness limited to vectors of positive components

Tags: positive-definite

Consider a square and symmetric real matrix. The positive definiteness, defined as, 
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j>0\qquad\forall \mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n,\ \mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}
$$
could be characterised by various means, for example

- by the positiveness of its eigenvalues,
- by the alternating sign of the coefficients of its characteristic polynomial,
- by the positiveness of the leading principal minors

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, considering the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
corresponding to the quadratic form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$, the positive definiteness conditions could be expressed as
$$
a>0,\ c>0,\ -\sqrt{ac}<b<\sqrt{ac}
$$
while for non negative values of $x,y$ (not both null) one obtains
$$
a>0,\ c>0,\ -\sqrt{ac}<b\qquad\quad
$$

There exist some general results about $x_i\geq0$ (not all null) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in particular for $n=3$?
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j>0\qquad\forall \mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in[0,\infty)^n,\ \mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}
$$

Comment: You better put a sum somewhere in the beginning, otherwise it is not the definition of positive definiteness...

Comment: @Bemte: it is an abuse of Einstein convention used frequently in mathematical physics, but OK, you're right.